# can't set undecorated for JDialog created by JOptionPane.createDialog

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, jdialog, awt-eventqueue

I have JDiolog created from JOptionPane

```
        var pane = new JOptionPane(e.getMessage(),JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
        var dialog = pane.createDialog("Error");
        dialog.setUndecorated(true);
        dialog.setBackground(new Color(0, 0,0,78));
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        return;
```

but this code throws exception

> ```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The dialog is displayable.
>   at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.setUndecorated(Dialog.java:1265)
>   at com.quiz.server.LoginDialog.lambda$new$1(LoginDialog.java:56)
>   blalablablabla.....
> ```

but I commented out these lines

```
    dialog.setUndecorated(true);
    dialog.setBackground(new Color(0, 0,0,78));
```

then it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code snippet will show the JOptionPane dialog without decorations:

```
    boolean defaultLFDecorated = JDialog.isDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated();
    try {
        JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("This is a message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
        JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog("Error");
        dialog.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.NONE);
        pane.setOpaque(false);
        ArrayList<Component> components = new ArrayList<Component>(Arrays.asList(pane.getComponents()));
        while(!components.isEmpty()) {
            Component c = components.remove(0);
            if(c instanceof JComponent) {
                ((JComponent)c).setOpaque(false);
            }

            if(c instanceof Container) {
                components.addAll(Arrays.asList(((Container)c).getComponents()));
            }
        }
        dialog.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 78));
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        dialog.dispose();
    }
    finally {
        JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(defaultLFDecorated);
    }
```

Comment: I cant set background color with it but its working  without decorations. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @noone I have modified the code snippet to walk the Components and setOpaque(false)